# How to join two tables and show in gridview in yii2?

Tags: join, gridview, yii2

I have three tables?
`s(s#,firstName,lastName)` , `p(p#,name)` and `sp(s#,p#,qty)`.
there are all relation in s model(created by gii).

codes:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {


        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' =>s::find(),

        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

and in index view:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],


        'firstName',
        'lastName',

        [
         'attribute'=>'qty',
         'value'=>'sp.qty'

        ]

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I want to show qty in grid view. but it doesn't show.
I want to show follow query in gridview:

```
select firstName,lastName,qty from s join sp on s.s#=sp.s#
```

what is the problem?

Comment: can you show your relation in s model

Comment: public function getSps()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Sp::className(), ['sId' => 'id']);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should check your relation:
it should be `hasOne` not `hasMany`

```
getSps() {
 return $this->hasOne(Sp::className(), ['sId' => 'id']); 
}
```

and you have to call for your relation with `sps` not just `sp` because your relation name is `getSps`

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],


        'firstName',
        'lastName',

        [
         'attribute'=>'qty',
         'value'=>'sps.qty'

        ]

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

- There are numerous way to do this.

**Method 1:**

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' =>p::find(),

        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

In your grid view:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        [
            //to be declared in PSearch Model
            'attribute' => 'first_name',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                // Relation will be setup in the model
                if ($data->sp) {
                    return $data->sp->s->first_name;
                } 
                return 'Display whatever is required';
            },
        ],

        [
            //to be declared in PSearch Model
            'attribute' => 'last_name',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                // Relation will be setup in the model
                if ($data->sp) {
                    return $data->sp->s->last_name;
                } 
                return 'Display whatever is required';
            },
        ],

        'name',


        [
            //to be declared in PSearch Model
            'attribute' => 'quantity',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                // Relation will be setup in the model
                if ($data->sp) {
                    return $data->sp->quantity;
                } 
                return 'Display whatever is required';
            },
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

If this doesn't help please leave a comment. Thank you!!

Comment: thanks for your anwer. but when I use  `return $data->sp->quantity;` it throw this error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: and when in use `return implode(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($data->sps, 'id', 'sId'));` it shows all rows of `qty` in one row and merge values of it in a cell !!!

Answer (score 0):

1. create search class

   ```
   class sSearch extend s {
       public $name;
       public $qnt;
       public functioin search()
       {
           return new ActiveDataProvider([
               'query' =>self::find()
                  ->select([
                    's.*',
                    'sp.qnt'
                  ])
                  ->innerJoin('sp','s.s = sp.s'),

           ]);
       }
   }
   ```
2. search class add to action

   ```
   public function actionIndex()
   {
       $search = new sSearch()
       return $this->render('index', [
           'dataProvider' => $search->search(),
       ]);
   }
   ```